# Facebook JSDK posting on user's friends wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to post on the user's friends wall trough javascript SDK. The basic function is that the user creates a team and invites his/her friends to join it.

Let's say I got an appropriate access token with all the needed permissions.

Now after the user selected a friend (for the sake of simplicity now this is one user with id 12345678), I call this:

```
FB.api('/12345678/feed', 'post', {
        name: 'Test post',
        caption: 'Test caption',
        link: 'https://my.example.com/invite/',
        description: 'Join my awesome team',
        message: 'Join my awesome team'
    },function(response) {console.log(response);});
```

My problem is that even though I get back a post ID successfully, nothing is shown on the selected user's wall. If I post to the user's feed with the SAME access token trough the Graph API explorer manually, it works.

What do I do wrong? How come I can't send this trough my app, yet I can use the Graph API to send a message? Both are unapproved apps by the 'friend' I try to send a message to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to post on your profile then check.

it may possible that post you are posting by default shown  to only me.

goto `facebook.com/developers/`

select your app .

click on permissons left side.

then check Default Activity Privacy to public.

and in basic setting check whether sandbox enabled or disabled.It should be disabled

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a post on test Facebook profile and login through that profile to check the post, issue might be with Privacy  2) `https://www.facebook.com/{profile_id}/posts/{post_id}` replace profile_id and post_id  in this url and access this url to see what it shows. 3) Check your configurations again if everything is fine (Toggle sandbox mode and check if it makes any difference)

Btw Facebook is planning to remove ability to post to friends walls via Graph API please check devloper roadmap --> https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ . This feature wont be available after some months.